# install Sitecore update packages with Powershell

Tags: powershell, sitecore, package

We create Sitecore .update packages using TDS and Visual Studio. The update packages can be installed using /sitecore/admin/updateinstallationwizard.aspx. Is there a way to install these packages using Powershell?

Thanks

Comment: Sitecore Powershell or Windows Powershell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the tooling you want to use. 
If you can work with [Sitecore PowerShell Extensions](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx), it has a convenient `Install-UpdatePackage` cmdlet (**not** the `Install-Package` - this one works with **regular** Sitecore packages exclusively) that can deploy them in your environment. You can [read more about it in our GitBook](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/appendix/commands/Install-UpdatePackage.html)

You can also create those using the `Get-UpdatePackageDiff` and `Export-UpdatePackage` if you do not have access to TDS.

Now to do this on the server directly that's just something that you would run from the Web UI using SPE ISE, but to upload those from your dev environment you can utilise the SPE Remoting again [as described in this Gitbook page](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/remoting.html)

If you don't have or want to have SPE deployed on your server you can utilise [Sitecore Ship](https://github.com/kevinobee/Sitecore.Ship) and automate that in Windows PowerShell without the use of Sitecore PowerShell Extensions. The functionality of Sitecore Ship module is limited to doing the task of deploying Sitecore Update packages but this might be just what you want.

Comment: If I want to generate a .update package for items/templates/layouts/etc modified after a certain date from TFS, is it possible? Right now we are using TDS to generate the packages, but as you may know, there is no way to generate package of only recently modified items. Of course, items can be marked as DeployOnce or AlwaysUpdate but with frequent item updates, it is not feasible to continue switching these settings on items.

Also, is installing a package via Powershell faster than installing it through /sitecore/admin/updateinstallationwizard.aspx?

Comment: That info I am afraid needs to be provided at the time of package creation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for Sitecore Powershell command: 
   `Install-Package [[-Path] ] [-InstallMode ] [-MergeMode ]`

More details can be found here:

https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/appendix/commands/Install-Package.html

Comment: `Install-Package` works with **regular** Sitecore packages, **not** the `.update`. More details in a separate attempt at an answer.